# How to call an API function using a view

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to fetch data from an API and render that data using a view.
I am not sure what is wrong.
Could someone please show me what I need to change in order to make it work ?

My fixtures.py:

```
def get_fixtures():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        settings.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CREDENTIALS_FILE,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
    )
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    events = service.events().list(calendarId='u6kmbrsrt5qr3r6gjrtsussomc@group.calendar.google.com').execute()
    
    fixtures = []
    for event in events['items']:
        fixture = {
            'summary': event['summary'],
            'start': event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date')),
            'end': event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date')),
        }
        fixtures.append(fixture)
```

My views.py :

```
def fixtures_view(request):
    fixtures = get_fixtures()
    return render(request, 'fixtures.html', {'fixtures': fixtures})
    print(fixtures)
```

There's nothing on my HTML page and nothing is being printed on the command prompt either.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_fixtures()` function has no return so it returns None.

Return the fixtures list at the end of the function like:

```py
def get_fixtures():
    # Your code here
    return fixtures
```